Does WebRTC need Server?
I have a simple question
based on this link
WebRTC

WebRTC (Web Real-time Communication) is an industry effort to enhance
the web browsing model. It allows browsers to directly exchange
realtime media with other browsers in a peer-to-peer fashion through
secure access to input peripherals like webcams and microphones.
Traditional web architecture is based on the client-server paradigm,
where a client sends an HTTP request to a server and gets a response
containing the information requested. In contrast, WebRTC allows the
exchange of data among N peers. In this exchange, peers talk to each
other without a server in the middle.

and I thought webRTC is like that but then
I saw this tutorial
WebRTC chat app
He creates a Node.js server and even uses WebSocket in his app. Now, I'm confused based on the definition that WebRTC technology must work with only peers, but now in this tutorial, a server is used. I want to know what exactly is the difference between client-server real-time communication and WebRTC.

server is needed only for the initial connection between the parties, to negotiate for them a secure channel, and you could use AJAX for that, for example

WebRTC media traffic can be peer-to-peer: video and audio traffic can go directly from the sender to the receiver.
However, in order to communicate two peers need to exchange some information, such as their IP addresses ("ICE candidates") and their cryptographic keys.  How they exchange this information is up to the application, but the usual solution is to use a server for that, called the "signalling server".
 signalling server
    /        \
   /          \   ICE candidates and
  /            \  cryptographic keys
 /    media     \
A ============== B

There are some exceptions to the above.  First, if direct communication is impossible (for example due to a mis-configured firewall), WebRTC will fall back to routing the media traffic through a "TURN" server.  Second, WebRTC is a fairly flexible protocol, and a lot of applications use it with a media server (an "SFU"), in which case all media traffic goes through the server.
